# What does the “Offset to the filename” stands for in an Index Record in NTFS

Tags: hex

The structure of the Index Record in *NTFS 3.1* is clear:

```
Offset      Description
-------------------------------------
0x00        MFT Reference of the file
0x08        Size of the index entry
0x0A        Offset to the filename
...
0x52        Filename
...
```

The filename is always located at `0x52`. So, why do we need the data stored on `0x0A`? And what does it include (Almost not `0x52`)?

Comment: Wait, what? Where did you get that information. [Here](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf)? For starters attributes (and the file name is an attribute in NTFS terms, IIRC), can be resident (inside the record) or non-resident (elsewhere). So your assumption that the file name ought to be at offset 0x52 is already wrong. But what you describe here looks more like an `ATTRIBUTE_RECORD_HEADER`? I think you need to give more information.